# Returning JSON in Model throws error in Controller

Tags: ember.js

I am an Ember newbie. When using the below model with Object, Ember complained `The value that #each loops over must be an Array` that I should use ArrayController. But changed it to `ArrayController` it complains `ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object..`

My intention was to object(s) from model in JSON format and access it in Object Controller.

```
App.FirstRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

     model: function(){
         return {"employees":[
         {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
         {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
         {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
         ]};
     }
});
```

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/faqatomusi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification to your bin:

You are returning Object as model in model hook. It is not Array, so your controller extends ObjectController.

Just Change the following code

```
{{#each item in model}}
```

to

```
{{#each item in model.employees}}
```

Working bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tedut/1/edit?html,js,output

My Suggestion:

Change your model to

```
 model: function(){
     return [
     {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
     {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
     {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
     ];
 }
```

and your controller would be

```
App.FirstController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
```